# How to compute the fundamental group of a specific identification space of the unit disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, quotient-spaces

Say that $X_n$ is the space defined by taking the unit disk in the complex plane (that is $\{z||z|\le 1\}$) and identifying points on the boundary of the disk as follows: if $|z|=1$ then  we identify $z$ with $z\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ (this means that each point on the boundary will be identified with $n-1$ other points and that points on the interior will not be affected). I am supposed to compute the fundamental group of this space but I am not sure how to proceed. I tried to do some easy cases. n=2 for example yields $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ since it's another theorem that the unit disk with antipodal points identified is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. I think that in general it is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Do I need to use Seifert Van Kampmen's theorem for this? If not, is there some way to directly compute it?

Comment: You can describe your space as the result of gluing a disk in a circle in a specific way. You can use that.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? That doesn't give me any direction for this problem.

Comment: You probably know how to describe the projective plane as the result of gluing a disk to a circle — generalize that.

Comment: To use van Kampen's theorem over, say, 2 open sets, you need to know the fundamental group of each of those open sets and their intersection, assuming the intersection is path connected. Here's a hint: what is the fundamental group of the circle modulo the equivalence in your question, and can you find two open sets so one of them is homotopic to this quotient of the circle?

Comment: Sorry, I realized my hint might be misleading. You still have to keep track of what happens to the generators on the intersection when they are mapped into the elements of the cover. That's where you can "see" what is happening.

Comment: We let A be a disk centered at the origin with radius smaller than 1 (say radius r) and we let B=p({z| .5r<|z|<=1}) where p is the quotient map that gives us the identification we want. Then it is clear that B deformation retracts onto the circle modulo the equivalence relation we have in question. It see that the fundamental group of A intersect B will be infinite cyclic, and the fundamental group of A will be trivial. What is not clear to me is how to come up with the fundamental group of B (equivalently, the fundamental group of the circle modulo the equivalence relation in question). @dl19

Comment: I should have deleted my earlier comment, which is not really what I wanted to say. The quotient of a circle mod the equivalence relation is still a circle. So van Kampen tells us that the fundamental group is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$. The subgroup that you need to quotient by is generated by the image of the generator on the intersection under the inclusion map to the nontrivial element of your open cover. This is precisely the content of van Kampen's theorem.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DanielLevine Sorry, could you please explain a little more about: the quotient of a circle mod the equivalence relation is still a circle? Do you mean they are homeomorphic? Or homotopic? Thank you!